# How many real roots does the following polynomial equation have?

Tags: polynomials, roots

$P_n(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+....+(n+1)x^n$
 Also given: n is an odd number.

Well; from the polynomial equation, it is clearly understood that all the roots have to be negative.

Also, there has to be at least 1 root; that is clear if we put $x=1$.

It would help if you could tell me how to proceed...

Comment: Why do you think that there is at least 1 root at $x=1$? This is a polynomial of $\mathbb{N}[X]$ of degree $n$ so it has exactly $n$ roots counted with multiplicity.

Comment: Change the title of the question, because the equation that you want to solve is not quadratic

Comment: We have $P_n(1)\ne 0$ and the polynomial is not quadratic for $n\ge 3$. You probably mean that $P_n(1)>0$ shows that there is at least one real root but this is guaranteed for a polynomial with odd degree anyway. Additionally : What is the question ?

Comment: You might mean $P_n(-1)=(1-2)+(3-4)+...+(n-(n+1))=-(n+1)/2<0$ to get the existence of at least one real root (in $[-1,0]$). But then again, every odd degree polynomial has at least one real root by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Your polynomial is the derivative of $$1+x+\cdots+x^{n+1} = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$ That right-hand side really ought to be easier to handle, in my opinion.

Comment: @BillO'Haran "exactly $n$ roots" is true in the complex numbers, I do not think this is the intent here, it seems that the real roots have to be determined (and perhaps the number of (negative) real roots)

Comment: @Peter My point is that the third sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @BillO'Haran It is unlucky formulated, but it makes sense if it is interpreted correctly, namely that $P_n(1)>0$ guarantees the existence of a real root because the function tends to $-\infty$, when $x$ tends to $-\infty$. However, this existence follows already from the odd degree.

Answer (score 3):

Since all coefficients of $P_n(x)$ is non-negative. $P_n(x) \ge P_n(0) = 1 > 0$ for all $x > 0$.
Independent of whether $n$ is even or odd, $P_n(x)$ doesn't have any non-negative root.

For odd $n$, notice

$$(x-1)^2 P_n(x) = (n+1)x^{n+2} - (n+2) x^{n+1} + 1$$

At $x = -r < 0$, we have
$$(r+1)^2 P_n(-r) = 1 -((n+1)r + (n+2))r^{n+1}$$
Notice RHS is strictly decreasing as $r$ increase from $0$. 
Together with the fact RHS is $1$ at $r = 0$ and goes to $-\infty$ as $r \to \infty$. There is one and only one $r > 0$ where $(r+1)^2P_n(-r)$ vanishes.

From this, we can conclude $P_n(x)$ has exactly one real root for odd $n$.

Answer (score 1):

As your function is a partial sum for the binomial series of $(1-x)^{-2}$, consider
\begin{align}
(x-1)P_n(x)&=-(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)+(n+1)x^{n+1}\\
(x-1)^2P_n(x)&=1-(n+2)x^{n+1}+(n+1)x^{n+2}
\end{align}

From the last form you can see by the Descartes rule of signs that there is exactly one negative root for odd $n$.

In a first, rather heuristic, approximation, the roots of the last expression are close to the roots of the two binomials in it, that is, close to $\frac{n+2}{n+1}$ and the roots of $x^{n+1}=\frac1{n+2}$. Remove from this root set the first one and $\sqrt[n+1]{\frac1{n+2}}$ as these correspond to the double root at $1$ of the factor $(x-1)^2$. Then there remains a real root around $x=-1$ with a closer approximation to $-\sqrt[n+1]{\frac1{2n+3}}$ while the other are close to complex unit roots.

More precisely, set $x=qv$ with $q^{n+1}=1$, $q\ne 1$ and $v\approx 1$. Then one approximation of the equation is $$0\approx 1-(n+2-(n+1)q)v^{n+1}$$ which has a solution close to $1$ of approximately
$$
v\approx ((n+2)-(n+1)q)^{-1/(n+1)}\approx(2n+3)^{-1/(n+1)}(1+\frac1{2n+3}(q+1))
$$ 
[image]

```
phi=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,160); 
for k in range(4,22): 
    n=2*k-1; rts = np.roots(range(n+1,0,-1)); 
    plt.plot(rts.real, rts.imag, '+', label="n=%d"%n); 
    r=(2*n+3)**(-1./(n+1)); q = np.exp(1j*phi); 
    x = r*q*(1+(q+1)/(2*n+3)); 
    plt.plot(x.real, x.imag, lw=0.2)

plt.plot(np.sin(phi),np.cos(phi), lw=0.4); plt.legend(); plt.grid(); plt.show()
```